# Prevent Form Resubmission With Javascript After Ajax Post (No Redirect)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, browser

A similar question has been asked before with regards to POSTing a form *without redirecting*, but none of the solutions actually have worked in my case, and those answers are about 8 years old. In my situation, I have a simple form that submits a few text fields to a URL using Ajax:

```
<form id="f">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button type="submit" form="f">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$("#f").submit(function() {
    var arr = $("#f").serializeArray();
    var name = arr[0].value;
    var ajaxConfig = {type: "post", url: "submit_form", data: {name: name}};
    $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

This works perfectly as far as submitting the data to the server goes. The POST request is sent and received, but whenever the page is visited again the browser will attempt to resubmit the data for no reason (Why?). This results in an invalid request being sent to my sites homepage and an HTTP 405 "Page not working error". The page will work again upon subsequent requests. This happens in both Chrome and Safari.

I've tried the `history.replaceState(null, null, location.href);`, which others have stated works for them, but for me it did not work, neither in Chrome or Safari.

Post/Redirect/Get is not a viable solution as I am wanting to stay on the same page. Please do not recommend that I use the Post/Redirect/Get solution as it does not fit my use case.

One solution is to not use the default "submit" functionality, and simply have the form be submitted through a custom javascript function and click handler:

```
<form id="f">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button form="f" onmousedown='submit()'>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    function submit() {
        var arr = $("#f").serializeArray();
        var name = arr[0].value;
        var ajaxConfig = {type: "post", url: "submit_form", data: {name: name}};
        $.ajax(ajaxConfig);

    });
</script>
```

But this answer seems to be hacky. Is there a way to submit using canonical form submit buttons without required resubmission upon the next page visit? Furthermore, why would forms be implemented such that they are resubmitted for no reason on page revisiting, even after it's been confirmed they've been submitted once before?

Edit:
Using preventDefault() does not do anything:

```
<script>
$("#f").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var arr = $("#f").serializeArray();
    var name = arr[0].value;
    var ajaxConfig = {type: "post", url: "submit_form", data: {name: name}};
    $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: When you use classic form submission, it will retain that in the browser history. So when you go back, it remembers that as the form submission. This would be the reason to use `onclick` and execute a function to make the AJAX call. By default this approach will prevent the issue. Modifying the history is the only other way to get around this issue (that I can think of atm). Using a click event is not hacky. It's fairly standard affair.

Comment: pass the event in submit function `submit(event)` and then prevent the default action. `function submit(event) { event.preventDefault() /** rest of the code here **/ }` Not sure if this will solve your problem. You can also use `click` event on the button. This is not considered hacky.

Comment: @Sudheer Prevent default didn't change anything - But if it's not hacky for me to not use classic form submission then I may as well not use classic form submission. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `preventDefault()` on your form submission event. 
It prevents the default action of the form - as form is supposed to reload your page every time it is submitted.

Read more at [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
<script>
$("#f").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var arr = $("#f").serializeArray();
    var name = arr[0].value;
    var ajaxConfig = {type: "post", url: "submit_form", data: {name: name}};
    $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work, in chrome or safari at least.